# How to save a for loop's output into an array for python images?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, keras, scikit-learn

I have a set of data that is being resized, however when I try to resize the array I get a memory error... My next move is to try to make a loop that will run the resize conversion on each image 1 at a time. I am trying to follow a keras code that adds another axis to the dataset so I can predict all of the training data images. I am unsure of how to set up this loop to save the data and go on to the next image of the 50,000 images. This is what I have so far. This is what the task asks: Your job is to make all images of the training set undergo the same feature extraction step, and use the resulting feature vectors as input to a conventional classfier.

```
from skimage import transform
#resized_xtrain =np.zeros((50000, 224, 224, 3))
for i in range (50000):
resized_xtrain= transform.resize(x_train[i], (224, 224, 3), order=1, mode='reflect')
```

With a .shape I get (224, 224, 3)

```
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('fc2').output)

#img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
#img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
#x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(resized_xtrain, axis=0)
```

This produces a shape of (1, 224, 224, 3) which is needed for the predict method.

```
x = preprocess_input(x)

fc2_features = model.predict(x)
fc2_features.shape
```

fc2 produces a `1, 4096`. How would I be able to store the 50,000 iterations into 1 array so I can use that data for a classifier?